# Visual studio wont install at all

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, installation, uninstallation

My question is answered. (LNK1104 is main answer, my answer is the fix to installation error). I've recently had a very big problem with the error LNK1104 using c++, and decided to uninstall visual studio 2013 several times. The last time I installed it to a partition D:, and literally nothing worked at all. Then I uninstalled, and now it won't let me tell it to install anywhere else but the D: drive.

I put the Visual Studio Express 2013 installation log in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/pN5UaQvS

(I replaced occurrences of my name with "MYNAME")

The log may contain the problem as to why I cannot install it to its right location.

[image: Picture showing Visual Studio 2013 grayed out]

I unallocated the second disk to make the D: drive a completely incompatible place to install to try to reset where it wants to install, but all I got was an Invalid drive error.

I am still completely unable to install visual studio anywhere, and it won't let me choose a place, is there any way at all this can be fixed? Can I never install visual studio on here again?

Also, since I unallocated the space it was trying to install to, I can't even get it to stop saying "Invalid drive." So even if I do attempt to install it, the install button is completely grayed out as well because its an invalid path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With LNK1104 error, you just only go to **Project Properties -> Linker -> and set /INCREMENTAL[:NO].**

Comment: This worked perfectly for the KNK1104 error, and I described in my answer how the installation failure was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a couple days of searching for ways to completely uninstall, I finally tried /uninstall /force cmd commands to forcefully remove any leftover files. After using these these commands and running the installer to reinstall Visual studio, I finally got it to successfully install to the main drive again. After I installed it, I unfortunately still got the LNK1104 error yet again... The problem demonstrated in this question has been solved with the forced uninstall of Visual Studio Express 2013.